# Utilizing a Queue

Tags: c#, .net, list, queue

I'm trying to store records of transactions all together and by category for the last 1, 7, 30 or 360 days. I've tried a couple things, but they've brutally failed. I had an idea of using a queue with 360 values, one for each day, but I don't know enough about queue's to figure out how that would work.

Input will be an instance of this class:

```
class Transaction
{
    public string TotalEarned { get; set; }
    public string TotalHST { get; set; }
    public string TotalCost { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

New transactions can occur at any time during the day, and there could be as many as 15 transactions in a day. My program is using a plain text file as external storage, but how I load it depends on how I decide to store this data.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: How you load it should depend on what you plan on doing with it.  What are you going to be doing with the `Transactions`?  A `Queue` is useful if you want to process them individually and in order.

Comment: You should not delete your question and re-ask it; you should simply edit your [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551262/utilizing-a-queue) if you have new information to provide.  On top of that, I still don't see enough information to see understand what exactly you want.

Comment: Queue or list or stack can be decide later. You class does not seem  right to me. It does not have enough information to store about when the transaction was happened

Comment: `What would be the best way to do this?` Do what?  It's not clear what the problem is?  You want to gather things by categories of 1, 7, 30 and 360 days? Step 1, Take @MillerKoijam 's advice and add a DateTime. Then you can group them into categories. What does storage have to do with categorizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're obviously after convenience rather than speed.  The typical usage you're expecting stores about 5400 transactions in total.  That's really small, and a single `ArrayList` ought to be fine.  When you want to query data out of it, just iterate through it, adding relevant items to another `ArrayList` and return that.

Just keep your data in sorted order - *ie* all new transactions get pushed onto the back of the list.  If you want to pull out by category, that should be just as easy as pulling out by day.

Keeping a single structure and copying queries out of it will make your life easier, especially if your class is used in multiple threads and requires locking.

To me, it seems like overkill to maintain indexes for faster lookup, or to use a database.  If a simple solution works well enough, then use it.  It's easier to maintain and less prone to error.

Comment: This, paired with seconds since epoch turned to days added to the class might work, I'll give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: If the data logically represents a queue then you should use a queue rather than an `ArrayList`.  In addition to performing much better, if it's what the data logically represents then using a queue will simply be *easier*.  Also note that `ArrayList` is completely depricated; use `List` at the very least.

Comment: Thanks @Servy I answered as a C++ programmer with limited C# knowledge.  I don't think this is as much about language as it is about design considerations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure a queue is exactly what you are looking for here.  A queue is something of an ephemeral data structure: it's not intended to keep things around for a while, and it's certainly not designed to let you slice and dice the data in the way you would like.

It sounds like your use case is crying out for a database.  Storing structured data, for a long period, with the intention of sorting or querying by various criteria is exactly what databases were invented for.

Comment: How easy is a structured database to implement? I've always used .txt files due to their simplicity, but if using a database is simple enough, I might make the switch.

Edit: this is how I'm doing databases right now:

Comment: There is certainly an overhead to using a database on a project: setting up and running the database server, adding the client libraries, creating the table schema and writing queries to insert and select data.  Fortunately Microsoft makes it pretty easy to get started with MSSQL on .NET projects, since much of the configuration works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class which tracks the elements added to it within a certain period. To use it:

```
    // creating
    var q = new RecentQueue<Transaction>(TimeSpan.FromDays(360)); // last 360 days
    var q = new RecentQueue<Transaction>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) // last 5 seconds

    // adding elements
    var t = new Transaction { Category = "cat1", TotalCost = "5",
                                TotalEarned = "3", TotalHST = "2" }
    q.Enqueue(t);

    // iterating 
    foreach (var element in q)
        // do whatever
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyCollections
{
    public class RecentQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        class RecentItem<U>
        {
            public U Item { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

        public TimeSpan Period { get; set; }
        private Queue<RecentItem<T>> _q;

        public RecentQueue(TimeSpan t)
        {
            Period = t;
            _q = new Queue<RecentItem<T>>();
        }

        public void Enqueue(T t)
        {
            Enqueue(t, DateTime.Now);
        }

        public void Enqueue(T t, DateTime date)
        {
            Cut();
            _q.Enqueue(new RecentItem<T> { Date = date, Item = t });
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Cut();
            foreach (var element in _q)
                yield return element.Item;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            Cut();
            foreach (var element in _q)
                yield return element.Item;    
        }

        private void Cut()
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            while (_q.Count > 0 && date - _q.Peek().Date > Period)
                _q.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I agree with couchand, the "real" solution is not this, or any other in-memory data structure. It is simply using a database, indexing it on the date and querying it.

The class I posted would actually be far more useful to some application that tracks fast-occuring events in a short period (last few seconds, etc), because then you don't want to pummel the DB with requests, you want high performance, and you don't care about saving the data.

If you're tracking 360 days worth of data, you want a database.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of the operations you want to do on your data before you decide on a data store. To me, it sounds like you want to

- Query by date and by time period
- Have the collection purge itself based on the age of the data it contains

Write a custom class that does the operations you need (and no more) and uses a backing store of an appropriate type.

Something like this:

```
class MyTransactions
{
  private DateTime? OldestDate   { get ; set ; }
  private Dictionary<DateTime,List<Transaction>> BackingStore { get ; set ; }
  private int RetentionPeriodInDays
  {
    get
    {
      DateTime now     = DateTime.Now.Date ;
      TimeSpan oneYear = now - now.AddYears(-1) ;
      int      days    = (int) oneYear.TotalDays ;
      return days ;
    }
  }

  public MyTransactions()
  {
    OldestDate = null ;
    BackingStore = new Dictionary<DateTime,List<Transaction>>();
  }

  public void Add( Transaction t )
  {
    if ( t == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("t");

    if ( this.BackingStore.Count > RetentionPeriodInDays )
    {
      this.BackingStore.Remove(this.OldestDate.Value ) ;
      this.OldestDate = this.BackingStore.Keys.Min() ;
    }

    DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date ;
    List<Transaction> transactions ;
    bool exists = this.BackingStore.TryGetValue(today,out transactions) ;
    if ( !exists )
    {
      transactions = new List<Transaction>();
      this.BackingStore.Add(today,transactions) ;
    }
    transactions.Add(t) ;

    if ( today < this.OldestDate )
    {
      this.OldestDate = today ;
    }

    return ;
  }

  public List<Transaction> TodaysData
  {
    get
    {
      DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date ;
      List<Transaction> value = new List<Transaction>( this.BackingStore[today] ) ;
      return value ;
    }
  }

  public List<Transaction> CurrentWeekData
  {
    get
    {
      DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date ;
      List<Transaction> value = this.BackingStore
                                    .Where( x => x.Key > today.AddDays(-7) )
                                    .SelectMany( x => x.Value )
                                    .ToList()
                                    ;
      return value ;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

One option, if you're going to take the "One slot for each day" approach would be a 2-dimensional array. An array 365 in length, and each slot in that array has its own array or list structure to keep track of the transactions for that day.

How to store it? I would use XML, but that's just a personal preference because I've had a lot of experience with serializing and deserializing XML in C#.

Or as another answer said, a database is perfect for what you're looking for structure-wise. Depends on the scale of this project.

Edit: Changed answer from hash table to 2-d array.

Comment: hash tables *don't* allow multiple entries per slot; you'd need to have the value of the table be a collection.  Next, when you go to add a new item there's no easy way to find "the oldest date" to remove it from the collection; you have to do a linear search.  This is simply not a structure well suited to this problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I realized what I meant when I was thinking "hash table"- I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, the actual `HashTable` class is depreciated, you should use `Dictionary`.

Comment: Oh, ok. When I said HashTable I wasn't actually trying to reference a C# type, but more just the idea behind the structure. I'll keep that in mind next time I need to use one though.